# Crop an audio with moviepy Python

Tags: python

I've extracted an audio from the video in python with library moviepy.

```
video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
audio = video.audio
```

How can I crop audio by 30 seconds?
So, for example, I have an audio 1:25 length

After cropping I will have an array of audios with length [[0:29],[30:59],[60:85]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **.crop()** function.

I have found a very useful code, you can refer to it [here](https://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Zulko/--video-editing---Cup-Song-Covers-Mix/blob/master/CupSongsCovers.ipynb).